# How can I read unsigned shorts using Python?

Tags: python, c++, qt, numpy

## Main question

I would like to understand how to read a C++ unsigned short in Python. I was trying to use `np.fromfile('file.bin',np.uint16)` but it seems it doesn't work. Refer to this as the main question.

### Case study:

For giving some more contest
I have an array of `unsigned shorts` exported as a binary file using C++ and `QDataStream` method of QT.

Header:

```
QVector<unsigned short> rawData;
```

**main.cpp**

```
QFile rawFile(QString("file.bin"));
rawFile.open(QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QDataStream rawOut(&rawFile);
rawOut.writeRawData((char *) &rawData, 2*rawData.size());
rawFile.close();
```

I'm trying to read it using Python and numpy but I can't find how to read unsigned shorts. From [literature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc953fe1.aspx) unsigned shorts should be 2 bytes so I have tried to read it using:

```
import numpy as np
np.readfromfile('file.bin',np.uint16)
```

However if I compare a single unsigned_value reading it with python and prining as a string using in C++:

```
Qstring single_value = QString::number(unsigned_value)
```

They are different.

Comment: Can you please show us how you "export" the data? Preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I hope it is enough

Comment: I'd experiment with `endedness`. Try '<u2' or '>u2'.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: @hpaulj thanks the solution is using '>u2' can you formalize your comment as an answer? So I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd experiment with endedness. Try `'<u2'` or `'>u2'`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

`'>'` reverses the order of the 2 bytes

```
In [674]: np.array(123, np.dtype('>u2')).tostring()
Out[674]: b'\x00{'
In [675]: np.array(123, np.dtype('<u2')).tostring()
Out[675]: b'{\x00'
In [678]: np.array(123, np.uint16).tostring()
Out[678]: b'{\x00'
```

Answer (score 1):

`rawOut.writeRawData((char *) &rawData, 2*rawData.size());` is writing loads of rubbish in your file. QVector is not directly castable to an array of `short` as you are trying to do.

Use the code below to write your data

```
for(const auto& singleVal : rawData)
rawOut << singleVal;
```

Comment: Thansk but I have to write a whole array not a single value.

Comment: @GM yes, that writes a whole array

Comment: It doesn't work it says ISO c++ forbids declaration of 'singleVal'

Comment: Old compiler... replace `for(const auto& singleVal : rawData)` with `foreach(const unsigned short& singleVal, rawData)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html)

```
import struct

with open('file.bin', 'rb') as f:
    unsigned_shorts = struct.iter_unpack('H', f.read())
    print(list(unsigned_shorts))
```

Example output:

```
>>>[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```